# Configure Search Pattern for LDAPLoginModule

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to modify the sample project LDAPLoginModuleProject by changing the LdapLoginModule to connect to my ActiveDirectory. But I'm not able to get it right.

I have a BPM 8.5 installed and use LDAP authentication using the same AD. So the configs in authenticationConfig.xml refers to the WAS security configs. But I'm not sure what needs to be set in ldapSecurityPrincipalPattern and ldapSearchFilterPattern. Regarding the placeholder {username}, where does it come from? it's from the login.html, or my AD configurations?

WAS Global Security

- Base Entry: OU=devUsers,DC=btpdev,DC=local
- Primary host name: 192.168.1.112
- Port: 389
- Federated repository properties for login: uid
- LDAP attribute for Kerberos principal name: userprincipalname
- Federated repositories property names to LDAP attributes mapping

  - samAccountName -> uid
  - userprincipalname -> kerberosId

Below is my configuration.

```
        <loginModule name="LDAPLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.LdapLoginModule</className>
        <parameter name="ldapProviderUrl" value="ldap://192.168.1.112:389"/>
        <parameter name="ldapTimeoutMs" value="2000"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSecurityAuthentication" value="simple"/>
        <parameter name="validationType" value="searchPattern"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSecurityPrincipalPattern" value="uid={username},OU=devUsers,DC=btpdev,DC=local"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSearchFilterPattern" value="(uid={username})"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSearchBase" value="OU=devUsers,DC=btpdev,DC=local"/>
    </loginModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer for a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23390696/440934

The placeholder {username} is replaced by the username entered by the user (via a Worklight Authenticator). The answer above describes what the ldapSecurityPrincipalPattern and ldapSearchFilterPattern are used for.